How to drop your chest voice? (Bass Voice)
I'm a 15yo Basso Profundo, with a comfortable E2-D4 chest-head range, subharmonic down to F1, falsetto up to A4.
I was wondering how to extend the chest range down to somewhere like the B1-C2.
This is my first post on stack, so if I did anything wrong, let me know!
Thanks!

Wait another year or two, until your body has caught up with your aspirations?

I'm a little bit disappointed that nobody else has answered.


I was wondering how to extend the chest range down to somewhere like the B1-C2.

This depends primarily on the length and mass of your vocal folds.  There are some short-term techniques to increase the mass, generally through inflammation.  This is not particularly helpful to the long-term health of your voice.
At 15 years, your voice has a lot of development still ahead of it, a good ten years or so.  Your vocal health will be best served by focusing on good technique rather than range.  If the low C is going to come, it will come.  If it doesn't, you probably don't want to force it: would you rather be a great bass-baritone or struggling with vocal nodules?
Concentrate on good posture, breathing, and flexibility.  Don't try to force your range in either direction.  But do exercise your voice where it is comfortable and see where it develops.  Be patient.  Above all, find a good teacher.
